# syntax error, unexpected end of file on my code

Tags: php, syntax

Sorry guys I cant figure out where is the error in my code it must be a simple `{`
this is a simple form to upload imgs to database, so if anyone want it feel free to use it .

```
<html>
<body> 
    <form method="post" action="">
        <p>Selecionar imagem:</p>
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <p>descricao:</p>
        <input name="descricao" type="text">
        <p>categoria:</p>
        <input name="categoria" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "galeria");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("galeria", $con);
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (id,lowsrc,fullsrc,description,category)
    VALUES
    ('','$_POST[fileToUpload]','$_POST[fileToUpload]','$_POST[descricao]','$_POST[categoria]')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
        {
            die('ERRO: '.mysql_error());
        }
        echo "adicionado";
        if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST))
        {
            $target_dir = "full/";
            $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
                if ($check !== false)
                {
                    echo "OK - ".$check["mime"].".";
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Não é uma imagem";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }
            }
            // Check if file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file))
            {
                echo "Ficheiro ja existe!";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000)
            {
                echo "Ficheiro muito grande!";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Allow certain file formats
            if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif")
            {
                echo "Apenas JPG, JPEG, PNG e GIF são permitidos";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0)
            {
                echo "ERRO";
                // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            }
            else
            {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
                {
                    echo "Upload Feito";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "ERRO";
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have parsed your code and it says you need to add an extra bracket `}` before the last closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add closing curly bracket `}` at the end